# Restoring labels to the default position?

Tags: labeling, qgis-3

I've been moving point labels around in qgis3, and I wonder if there are some way to back all them to their default position. And beyond: Can I switch between label ubications? 
Lest's imagine I want them over the point sometimes and others linked to the point with a line, but away from the point. I already know how to make the line link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature turns on the 'data-defined' settings for label placement and uses an in-memory column called AUXILLARY_STORAGE_LABEL_POSITIONX and Y.

Seems the option to clear these is hidden, but:

Where the COORDINATE X and COORDINATE Y elements are activated, click the ASSISTANT option to turn this feature on.

Click the BACK button to go back to the main label panel.

There is now an option to CLEAR the values being used by the AUXILLARY_STORAGE_LABEL_POSITIONX and Y columns. Click CLEAR and the labels will reset their position.

Comment: In QGIS 3.x you open the Layer Properties, and click Auxiliary Storage.  An Auxiliary Layer button on the lower left allows you to Clear, Delete, or Export the aux tables.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can also right click where I highlighted to deactivate the "holding it to a position" feature. This button will turn gray, then you are free again!

I only found this out because of the two fine people that helped before me. Thank you all for saving us of more QGIS-cortisol!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
I needed to export the layer again, go in the properties and delete the `auxiliary_storage_labeling_positionx` and `auxiliary_storage_labeling_positiony`.
Move again the label and choose a field that is unique per object.